# A reproducible pseudo-random library for C++

Tags: c++, random-number-generator

Since C++11, the C++ standard library contains high-quality facilities for random number generation, divided into *engines* (things that produce random bits) and random distributions and algorithms that are driven by a user-provided engine.

Some of the engines are deterministic, so that with a given seed they are specified to produce a particular sequence of random bits. But this is not enough to produce portable software that has the *same* pseudo-random behaviour everywhere given the same random seed. The details of the random distributions (e.g. [`uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution), [`chi_squared_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/chi_squared_distribution), etc.) and of algorithms (such as [`shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)) are not specified, and thus may produce different results on different platforms.

I would like random distributions and algorithms that are deterministic and reproducible, ideally using a C++11 random number engine as the source of randomness. Does a library like that exist?